# Can't get a proper image source with laravel-mix + vueJS

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, laravel-mix

I'm using laravel-mix withe vueJS and I'm having issue on how to properly set-up the image directory.

Here's my initial mix set-up

```js
mix
  .js("resources/js/app.js", "public/js")
  .sass("resources/sass/app.scss", "public/css")
  .copy("resources/assets", "public/images/" );
```

as you can see, I'm copying all the content of `resources/assets` folder to `public/images/` folder

so this image `assets/svg/logo-white.svg` will be on `images/svg/logo-white.svg`

Now here's where I'm lost.

```js
//using this 
src="/assets/svg/logo-white.svg"
//result is obviously same (wrong url)
src="/assets/svg/logo-white.svg"

//using this
src="@/assets/svg/logo-white.svg"
// the result is (wrong url it lacks svg folder)
src="/images/logo-white.svg?c381d0781c93aa7ea138a64f7ea3f17d"

//using this
:src="'@/assets/svg/logo-white.svg'"
//result (another wrong)
src="@/assets/svg/logo-white.svg"
```

if I add `.setResourceRoot("")` to my mix config

```js
//using this
src="@/assets/svg/logo-white.svg"
//results to this,
src="http://localhost:8080/images/logo-white.svg?c381d0781c93aa7ea138a64f7ea3f17d"
//which supposedly a wrong URL but its weirdly working 
//I have no idea why its showing the images when the image is on /images/svg/ folder not in /images/
```

So as you can see, using `src="@/assets/blabla.jpg"` only work if all my images are inside the root of `images` folder, but doesn't work inside child folder of the images folder.

and adding `.setResourceRoot("")` works in a mysterious way which I dont really want to gamble as I'm not sure what will happen with this on production

would appreciate any help on this and clarification on how I can properly get the image url and why its behaving this way